# User message page has broken text box

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

In the 'contact user' diamond mod tool, the textbox where we enter the message to the user is shifted way over to the right (this is in Firefox 13):

[image: screenshot of textbox shifted to the right]

Comment: Norepro on Chrome 19.

Comment: I can't repro this. what browser/version are you using?

Comment: ...Firefox 13, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: [I see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127903/wonky-css-on-mod-message-page) this has been reported and reproduced per the main meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to repro this in FF13. The fix will be in the next prod build.